# Sprite animation with SDL2

Tags: c, animation, sdl, c99

For the past few days I've been trying to learn how to animate 2D sprites using SDL2. For that purpose, I've taken a 6 frames animation from a Pokémon game and made a PNG image out of it :

[image: Leaf 6 frames animation]

The way I figured out would work fine is is by creating an array `leaf_frames` (Leaf being the name of the character I used) containing the position and size of each frame in the image, and have another array `leaf_frames_indices` containing the index of the frame in `leaf_frames` to be displayed at a certain time into the animation. Each time I want to display a frame, I will simply tell the `SDL_RenderCopy` function which portion of the image to copy on the screen using those arrays and the current frame (given by `current_frame`). This is how I implemented it.

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

#include "config.h"


void keyboard_poll (SDL_Event *, int *);
SDL_Texture *load_image (SDL_Renderer *, const char *);


#define len(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))
#define eprintf(...) fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
#define key_pressed(keys, keysold, key) (keys[key] && !keysold[key])
#define key_released(keys, keysold, key) (!keys[key] && keysold[key])


void
keyboard_poll (SDL_Event *event, int *keys)
{
    SDL_Scancode keycode = event->key.keysym.scancode; /* not necessary, but makes the following code easier to read and write */

    if (keycode < SDL_NUM_SCANCODES) { /* out of bounds safety check */
        if (event->type == SDL_KEYDOWN) keys[keycode] = 1;
        if (event->type == SDL_KEYUP)   keys[keycode] = 0;
    }
}

SDL_Texture *
load_image (SDL_Renderer *renderer, const char *image_path)
{
    SDL_Surface *image_surface = IMG_Load(image_path);
    if (!image_surface) {
        eprintf("Could not load image %s : %s\n", image_path, IMG_GetError());
        return NULL;
    }

    SDL_Texture *image_texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, image_surface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(image_surface);

    return image_texture;
}

int
main (void)
{
    int retval = EXIT_SUCCESS;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        eprintf("Cannot initialize SDL : %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        retval = EXIT_FAILURE;
        goto cleanup_exit;
    }

    int img_flags = IMG_INIT_PNG; /* check whether what was asked to be initialized has been initialized or not, ignore the rest */
    if ((IMG_Init(img_flags) & img_flags) != img_flags) {
        eprintf("Cannot initialize SDL_image : %s\n", IMG_GetError());
        retval = EXIT_FAILURE;
        goto cleanup_sdl;
    }

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(CONF_APP_NAME, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, CONF_WINDOW_WIDTH, CONF_WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0);
    if (!window) {
        eprintf("Cannot create window : %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        retval = EXIT_FAILURE;
        goto cleanup_img;
    }

    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if (!renderer) {
        eprintf("Cannot create renderer : %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        retval = EXIT_FAILURE;
        goto cleanup_window;
    }

    SDL_Texture *leaf_sprite = load_image(renderer, "leafchan-animated.png");
    if (!leaf_sprite) {
        retval = EXIT_FAILURE;
        goto cleanup_renderer;
    }

    /* initialization ends here, declare some "quick and dirty" data to be used with the animation */

    SDL_Rect leaf_frames[] = { /* the array contains the coordinates of each frame */
        {.h = 19, .w = 16, .x =  0, .y = 0},
        {.h = 19, .w = 16, .x = 16, .y = 0},
        {.h = 19, .w = 16, .x = 32, .y = 0},
        {.h = 19, .w = 16, .x = 48, .y = 0},
        {.h = 19, .w = 16, .x = 64, .y = 0},
        {.h = 19, .w = 16, .x = 80, .y = 0}
    };

    SDL_Rect destrect = {
        .x = 0,
        .y = 0,
        .h = CONF_WINDOW_HEIGHT,
        .w = CONF_WINDOW_WIDTH
    };

    int leaf_frames_indices[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
    int current_frame = 0;
    int total_frames = len(leaf_frames_indices);

    int running = 1;
    int should_quit = 0; /* might be better off in a flags[] array ? */
    SDL_Event event;

    int keys[SDL_NUM_SCANCODES] = {0}; /* group those two in a struct ? */
    int keysold[SDL_NUM_SCANCODES] = {0};

    /* actual game loop */

    while (running) {

        /* read all events, update keyboard state */

        memcpy(keysold, keys, sizeof(keys));

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            keyboard_poll(&event, keys);

            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                should_quit = 1;
        }

        /* react to events */

        if (key_released(keys, keysold, CONF_KEY_EXIT) || should_quit)
            running = 0;

        /* draw */

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, CONF_CLEAR_COLOR, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, leaf_sprite, &leaf_frames[leaf_frames_indices[current_frame]], &destrect);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

        /* dirty time management, for demo purposes */

        SDL_Delay(100);

        /* used to be a 4 lines if else statement, but I just find one-liners to be more elegant, personal taste */
        current_frame = (current_frame < (total_frames - 1)) ? current_frame + 1 : 0;
    }

    /* cleanup */

    SDL_DestroyTexture(leaf_sprite);
cleanup_renderer:
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
cleanup_window:
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
cleanup_img:
    IMG_Quit();
cleanup_sdl:
    SDL_Quit();
cleanup_exit:
    return retval;
}
```

config.h:

```
#define CONF_APP_NAME       "Animations SDL2"

#define CONF_WINDOW_WIDTH   128
#define CONF_WINDOW_HEIGHT  152

#define CONF_PIXELFORMAT    SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888
#define CONF_CLEAR_COLOR    0, 5, 25

#define CONF_KEY_EXIT       SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE
```

And sure enough once I start it the animation runs perfectly :

[image: Animated preview]

Now that everything works fine, and that I'm pretty satisfied with my [error handling](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/04/27/using-goto-for-error-handling-in-c/), I'm still unsure as for the animation method I used and how I could group all of these things.

My first improvement suggestion would be to create a struct and have all of the animation-related data inside it, but then I feel that's a bit too specific to animations, and would not mix well with functions that use static sprites. What I could do as well, is to have a `Sprite` struct which would work for both animated and static sprites via an element `.animated` specifying whether or not the sprite is animated, so the drawing function knows how to handle it. Or maybe I could consider every sprite to be an animation, with static sprites only having one frame, which would spare me the need to write multiple implementations of drawing functions.

How should I go about this? I'm unsure how to pack all this together and have it be consistent. Or maybe there's a better way to deal with animations?

Note : I'm using the C99 standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can improve the time management by adding a millisecond counter and testing against that. This allows other things to run/animate as well while the sprite is waiting on the next frame. `delay` is usually a very bad idea for timing when doing interactive programs or when multiple things are being delayed.

```
int current_frame = 0;
int total_frames = len(leaf_frames_indices);
uint32 frame_last_changed = 0;

uint32 time = 0;

...

while (running) {
    time = SDL_GetTicks(); 
    //...


    if(frame_last_changed+100 > time){

        current_frame = (current_frame < (total_frames - 1)) ? current_frame + 1 : 0;
        frame_last_changed = time;
    }
}
```

The `100` delay can for example be added to the animation struct so animations can have different timings. A special value of 0 can mean not animated.

Comment: I am aware that delays are bad for time management, and indeed I do not use them when making actual games. In that case I really only wanted to focus on the animation itself, plus I'm using fixed time-steps in my other projects or "ticks",  hence the lack of time-based values in my animation code, but in the end it doesn't make much of a difference. I really like the idea of 0 delay = no animation though, I'll implement that. Thanks !